# can't get response fro Url

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

i'm try to get json file from mvc 4 application using webapi but i get an error in asynctask doinbackground method

the erro is in the json parser

```
Buffer Error", "Error converting result null pointer exception
```

and there is other error but those errors because there is no response from the server

i tried to debug my code and when i reach the line of this code the app crash

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String Url) throws JSONException
    {

        try {
            Log.d("tony","6"+Url);
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // to connect to http
            Log.d("tony","7"+Url);
            HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet(Url);
            Log.d("tony","8"+httpGet.getMethod());
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

i m using iis 8.0 
the json parser

```
 package com.haddad.tony;



import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is;
    static JSONObject jObj;
    static String json = "";

    public JSONParser()
    {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String Url) throws JSONException
    {

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // to connect to http
            HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet(Url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet); //get response from the url

            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity(); // extract data from response

            is = httpEntity.getContent(); // putting the extracted data in inputstream

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String Line = null;

            //Adding json!
            while ((Line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(Line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception

            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {
            Log.d("ss",json);
            jObj = new JSONObject(json); // parse the string to json Object
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        //this part is secondary. used when JSON has hidden string within the http to clean we use this return with throwing exceptions
        return new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1)); 
    }

    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String Url, String Method, List<NameValuePair> params)
    {
        try {

            if (Method == "POST")
            {
                // request method is post
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }
            else if(Method == "GET")
            {

                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                Url += "?" + paramString;

                Log.d("URL", Url);

                 HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(Url);
                 HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }   
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String Line = null;

            while ((Line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(Line + "\n");
            }

            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.d("myjson",json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try{
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return jObj;
    }

}
```

any help?

Comment: hey tony if i help you again, will @Fadi take it and submit it again?

Comment: no the reason because i accept his answer because he told me the answer before i ask the question but i wasn't sure from his solution so this time no he doesn't have answer :(

Comment: post your JSON parser!

Answer (score 0):

i fixed my problem by Bind my application to my public IP address

in the `IIS applicationhost.config` in `D:\Documents\IISExpress\config`

using this

```
  <site name="StopeAndShop" id="15">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\Desktop\StopeAndShopTEST\StopeAndShopTEST\StopeAndShop" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:2100:localhost" />
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:2100:myip address" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
```

and allow incomming connection using this command

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://myip address:2100/ user=everyone
```